# How can I implement a pager for the articles in this Laravel 8 blogging application?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am working on a **blogging application** in Laravel 8.

Un the **ArticlesController** controller I have:

```
class ArticlesController extends FrontendController {

   public function index() {
        // All articles
        $articles = Article::paginate(12);
        return view('themes/' . $this->theme_directory . '/templates/index', 
            [
                'theme_directory' => $this->theme_directory,
                'articles' => $articles
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

#### The goal

The goal is for the posts to have a pager, with links *only to the next and previous articles*, not a pagination.

```
<!-- Pager -->
@if($articles->hasPages())
    <div class="clearfix">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="prev">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
            </li>
            <li class="next">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">&larr; Newer Posts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

#### The problem

The default pagination code, of course, does not work for this:

```
@if($articles->hasPages())
    {!! $articles->withQueryString()->links() !!}
@endif
```

###### What is a viable solution for making this pager work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Simple pagination

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#simple-pagination

A simple view with Previous and Next buttons only is shipped with Laravel.  You need to first run `php artisan vendor:publish` and then select Laravel Pagination.

A vendor/pagination folder will be created in the views folder, containing different layouts

You can then tell Laravel to your choice of layout by registering it in a Service Provider.

Full instructions at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem, using the section of the documentation indicated by @Snapey:

```
@if($articles->hasPages())
    <div class="clearfix">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="next">
                <a class="btn btn-primary {{ $articles->onFirstPage() ? 'disabled' : '' }}" href="{{ $articles->previousPageUrl() }}">&larr; Newer Posts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="prev">
                <a class="btn btn-primary {{ $articles->onLastPage() ? 'disabled' : '' }}" href="{{ $articles->nextPageUrl() }}">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```